# Trying to convert IList to List in order to AddRange

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a `IList`. I try to call `ToList` and then `AddRange`.

However, the `ToList()` overwrite all the results. How come?

```
private void AddAliasesThatContainsCtid(string ctid, IList<MamConfiguration_V1> results)
{

...
    foreach (var alias in aliases)
    {
        var aliasId = "@" + alias;

    results.ToList().AddRange(mMaMDBEntities.MamConfigurationToCTIDs_V1.Where(item => item.CTID == aliasId)
                             .Select(item => item.MamConfiguration_V1)
                             .ToList());
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "overwrite"? What is being overwritten?

Comment: Are you trying to append to the end of your existing `IList`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.ToList()` does not convert an `IEnumerable<T>` to a `List<T>`, it creates and returns a new list filled with the values of the enumerable.

So your `result.ToList()` will create a new list and fill it with some data. But it will not change the contents of the object referenced by the result parameter.

In order to actually change the contents of the `result` parameter you have to use the `.Add` method of it or if your design allows it change the type of `result` to `List<..>`.

Comment: So `out` attribute would have helped?

Comment: @EladBenda it depends whether the parameter is an input or output parameter, or both. If it's truly an output parameter you can use `out`, create a new `List<..>` and then at the end assign that list to `result`. Or simply return the list instead of nothing (assuming it's an output parameter).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is equivalent:

```
// Create new List by calling ToList()
var anotherList = results.ToList();
anotherList.AddRange(...);
```

So, you actually add items into `anotherList`, not `result` list at all.

To get the correct result, two approaches:

1:

Declare `results` as `out` and assign back:

```
results = anotherList;
```

Or:

```
results = results.ToList().AddRange(...)
```

2:

Use `Add` method supported by `IList` instead of `AddRange`

Comment: While your explanation is perfect your solution won't work in this case because `results` is just a method parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IList<T> AddRange<T>(this IList<T> list, IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        foreach (var r in range)
        {
            list.Add(r);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: r can be T instead of var

Comment: Why isn't .addRange() working with this?

Answer (score 0):

Although `IList<T>` doesn't have an `AddRange()`, it *does* have `Add()`, so you *could* write an extension method for `IList<T>` that would let you add a range to it.

If you did, your code would become:

```
private void AddAliasesThatContainsCtid(string ctid, IList<MamConfiguration_V1> results)
{
...
    results.AddRange(mMaMDBEntities.MamConfigurationToCTIDs_V1
        .Where(item => item.CTID == aliasId)
        Select(item => item.MamConfiguration_V1));
   }
}
```

Compilable sample implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IList<string> list = new List<string>{"One", "Two", "Three"};
            Print(list);
            Console.WriteLine("---------");

            var someMultiplesOfThree = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(n => (n%3 == 0)).Select(n => n.ToString());
            list.AddRange(someMultiplesOfThree); // Using the extension method.

            // Now list has had some items added to it.
            Print(list);
        }

        static void Print<T>(IEnumerable<T> seq)
        {
            foreach (var item in seq)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    // You need a static class to hold the extension method(s):

    public static class IListExt
    {
        // This is your extension method:

        public static IList<T> AddRange<T>(this IList<T> @this, IEnumerable<T> range)
        {
            foreach (var item in range)
                @this.Add(item);

            return @this;
        }
    }
}
```