# Extension Method not Returning Correct Collection

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am using an extension method which shuffles a generic list.  This works

```
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
  {
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    int n = list.Count;
    while (n > 1)
    {
      byte[] box = new byte[1];
      do provider.GetBytes(box);
      while (!(box[0] < n * (Byte.MaxValue / n)));
      int k = (box[0] % n);
      n--;
      T value = list[k];
      list[k] = list[n];
      list[n] = value;
    }
  }
```

I am trying trying to create another extension method which would utilize Shuffle(), but would shuffle the items in a list in groups based on a defined group size.  This method seems to work when debugging the extension method, but the source list in the calling code still contains the original list after the extension call:

```
    public static void GroupRandomize<T>(this IList<T> sourceList, int groupSize)
  {
    List<T> shuffledList = new List<T>();
    List<T> tempList = new List<T>();
    int addCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceList.Count; i++)
    {
      tempList.Add(sourceList[i]);
      // if we've built a full group, or we're done processing the entire list
      if ((addCounter == groupSize - 1) || (i == sourceList.Count - 1))
      {
        tempList.Shuffle();
        shuffledList.AddRange(tempList);
        tempList.Clear();
        addCounter = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        addCounter++;
      }
    }
    sourceList = shuffledList;
  }
```

How do I ensure the shuffled list is stored properly into the source list?

Comment: The first example modifies the contents of list.  The 2nd example does not modify the contents of sourceList.  You "try" to replace what sourceList points to with an assignment of shuffledList, but this change is only local unless you use `ref`.

Comment: When you do `sourceList = shuffledList` you're assigning the *local* `sourceList` variable to the object referenced by `shuffledList` - not changing the original *list*. This is relevant: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: The cause has nothing to do with extension methods. You are **modifying a parameter**, which to me, warrants a **severe warning** (except _maybe_ in the most trivial, well-commented cases at the top of the method).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sourceList is actually a local variable. 
Might be better to `return shuffedList;`

```
var newList = caller.GroupRandomize<T>(5) ;
```

Comment: Agreed, I usually try to avoid mutating the value of the object I am extending in extension methods.

Comment: For .NET 4.5 with a Microsoft NuGet package, you can better express the contract by taking an [IImmutableList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467165%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
sourceList = shuffledList;
```

This will do nothing unless you are using a `ref` parameter. You *could* change your method so that it modifies the sourceList directly:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sourceList.Length; i++)
    sourceList[i] = shuffledList[i];
```

But I'd recommend changing your approach so that the extension methods return new, shuffled lists, leaving the original lists intact. So instead of:

```
var list = GetList();
list.Shuffle();
```

... you would say:

```
var list = GetList().Shuffle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a regular method instead of an extension so you can pass it in by reference:

```
public static void GroupRandomize<T>(ref IList<T> sourceList, int groupSize) {
    // ... stuff
    sourceList = shuffledList;
}
```

Comment: This would work but I would consider passing the list by reference rather than just returning the resulting list to be a poor decision.

Comment: Awww, what could possibly go wrong? :)  Out of curiosity, though, why?  It's true that it would be just as easy to pass the reference back but do you know of problems that passing by ref could potentially cause?

Comment: I've been reading a bit about functional programming and one of its strong points seems to be immutability, and no side effects. Which sounds nice.
If you have a domain A it always map to a new range B. You don't change domain A itself. But there is nothing stopping you from passing the list by reference of course

Comment: @FrancineDeGroodTaylor It's just not a good habit to get into. Objects tend to be passed around a lot and if you start passing things by reference when you don't need to, you'll quickly get yourself into a very volatile situation where lots of different methods are all sharing the same instance of a particular reference and one seemingly inocuous assignment can cause all kinds of (very difficult to debug) craziness elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't want to change the header of the method, you could do the something like:

```
sourceList.Clear();
sourceList.AddRange( shuffledList );
```

**Edit:**

As stated by [bperniciaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/652010/bperniciaro), The `AddRange` method is not available in the `IList<T>` interface.

[StriplingWarrior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120955/striplingwarrior) already suggested an implementation that does what `AddRange` would do, so instead I will just improve his answer a little by pointing to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16382974/432932), by [hvostt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2126634/hvostt), that implements `AddRange` as an extension method of `IList<T>`.

Comment: AddRange() method is not available to an IList<T>

Comment: Woops, I didn't notice the `I` in front of `IList`. You are right. I will change my answer to reflect that. Thanks.